# Forgot to rm refs/original after git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-gc

I forgot to `rm refs/original` after `git filter-branch` and did `git gc`, which cleared `refs`. I also committed into the new repo, and would like to keep these commits.

The extracted branch has a size of a few kilobytes, but `.git` still weights 80 MB, just like before the filtering.

Now `refs` is empty, and I cannot easily delete `refs/original` anymore. How can I still remove the originals? I would like to avoid having to `filter-branch` again if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your refs got packed (`git gc` runs `git pack-refs`).  That makes no changes to the refs themselves, except that rather than having each one in a separate file, they're all in the "packed" fie.

You simply need to delete the `refs/origina/` refs.  In theory using `git update-ref -d` on each one should work, but if there are many, it's probably easier to open `.git/packed-refs` in your editor and manually delete all the `refs/original/` lines.

You might also need to clear out reflogs.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1256452) for more.

Answer (score 0):

> `git gc` runs `git pack-refs`

If you start deleting refs, make sure to use Git 2.24+ (Q3 2019): "`git pack-refs`" can lose refs that are created while running, which is getting corrected.

See [commit a613d4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a613d4f8176593e560628b174c3e10cfac3f6d58) (31 Jul 2019) by [Sun Chao (`sunchao`)](https://github.com/sunchao).
<sup>(Merged by [Sun Chao -- `sunchao` --](https://github.com/sunchao) in [commit a613d4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a613d4f8176593e560628b174c3e10cfac3f6d58), 02 Aug 2019)</sup>

> ### pack-refs: always refresh after taking the lock file
>
> When a packed ref is deleted, the whole packed-refs file is rewritten to omit the ref that no longer exists.
>   However if another `gc` command is running and calls `pack-refs --all` simultaneously,
>   there is a chance that a ref that was just updated lose the newly created commits.
>
> Through these steps, losing commits on newly updated refs can be demonstrated:

```sh
  # step 1: compile git without `USE_NSEC` option
  Some kernel releases do enable it by default while some do
  not. And if we compile git without `USE_NSEC`, it will be easier
  demonstrated by the following steps.

  # step 2: setup a repository and add the first commit
  git init repo &&
  (cd repo &&
   git config core.logallrefupdates true &&
   git commit --allow-empty -m foo)

  # step 3: in one terminal, repack the refs repeatedly
  cd repo &&
  while true
  do
    git pack-refs --all
  done

  # step 4: in another terminal, simultaneously update the
  # master with update-ref, and create and delete an
  # unrelated ref also with update-ref
  cd repo &&
  while true
  do
    us=$(git commit-tree -m foo -p HEAD HEAD^{tree}) &&
    git update-ref refs/heads/newbranch $us &&
    git update-ref refs/heads/master $us &&
    git update-ref -d refs/heads/newbranch &&
    them=$(git rev-parse master) &&
    if test "$them" != "$us"
    then
      echo >&2 "lost commit: $us"
      exit 1
    fi
    # eye candy
    printf .
  done
```

> Though we have the packed-refs lock file and loose refs lock files to avoid updating conflicts, a ref will lost its newly commits if racy stat-validity of `packed-refs` file happens.
>   The best path forward is just always refreshing after take the lock file of `packed-refs` file.